# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQuote() on null

Tags: cart, magento2.3, phtml, quote

I'm trying to get store information from Shopping cart page 
[image]

To do so I have created a module

Following is my block file

```
<?
   namespace Magento\History\Block;
   class ViewQuote extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {    
       protected $_cart;    
       protected $_checkoutSession;    

       public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            ...
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
            array $data = []
       )
       {
           $this->_cart = $cart;
           $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

           parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

   public function getCart()
   {        
       return $this->_cart;
   }

   public function getCheckoutSession()
   {
        return $this->_checkoutSession;
   }
 }
```

And in my .phtml file, I'm calling like this

```
<?php
    // Get all items in cart

    $quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllItems();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }

    // Get total items and total quantity in cart

    $totalItems = $quote->getItemsCount();
    $totalQuantity = $quote->getItemsQty();

    //Get subtotal and grand total price of cart

    $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
    $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();

    //Get billing and shipping addresses

    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
```

But it's not working and showing an error :
[image]

I do not know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

A few things here:

- Your opening tag is only `<?` instead of `<?php`
- Magento recommends against injecting sessions into your constructors
- You should not make a session available in a template. Whatever you need from the session should be wrapped up in block logic
- Magento provides a cart helper class which provides both cart and quote. Rather than accessing the session directly, let Magento determine how to provide those objects.
- Magento coding standards state that your properties should be private, not protected, unless you specifically intend to extend your class and make those properties available to the child class
- Magento coding standards state that you should no longer prefix your properties and function names with an underscore.

This should work for you:

```
<?php

namespace Magento\History\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Class ViewQuote
 *
 * @package Magento\History\Block
 */
class ViewQuote extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    private $cartHelper;

    /**
     * ViewQuote constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper
     * @param Template\Context              $context
     * @param array                         $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper,
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->cartHelper = $cartHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    public function getCart()
    {
        return $this->cartHelper->getCart();
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    public function getQuote()
    {
        return $this->cartHelper->getQuote();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, I already edit the code but it still shows me an error      : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getQuote() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\History\view\frontend\templates\index.phtml

Comment: If you're still getting null, then you either have a customization that is interfering with the session or perhaps there is something wrong with your VM and sessions are not being initialized. The code I provided should work otherwise.

Comment: Are you doing any overrides or modifications that would affect sessions?

Comment: Also, I noticed that your class is namespaced with "Magento". Are you overriding a core block?

Comment: You can see my .phtml file above, I just create two file block and index.phtml.

Comment: Can you help me edit the .phtml file, please? I think it has a problem but I do not know where, I am new to Magento

Comment: You should change `$quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();` to `$quote = $block->getQuote();`. If that still doesn't work, the problem isn't with the template itself but somewhere else in your codebase.

Comment: Yes, It still not work for me, but anyway, thank you very much

Comment: Can you post the XML you use to make your class and template render on the page? There could be an error in there.

Comment: Yes, it's here     <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\History\Block\ViewQuote" name="viewquote" template="Magento_History::index.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>

Comment: it shows this error:  Call to a member function getAllItems() on null

Comment: If the name of the XML file is checkout_cart_index.xml, you should remove layout="1column". That is already declared and shouldn't be redeclared. Otherwise, your XML looks ok

Comment: The issue lies elsewhere in your codebase.

Comment: I think the issue in index.phtml file, it shows this: Call to a member function getAllItems() on null

Comment: It's not. The issue is the both the checkout session and the cart helper are returning null when you are expecting an instance of the quote. The problem is elsewhere, not in the template.

Comment: Do I need to create a helper file?

Comment: No. I'd review any other custom code you've written and third party extensions you've installed to determine why you dont have a checkout session.

Comment: Yes, thank you, @Shawn Abramson

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found a solution. Update your `index.phtml` file with below code

```
    $quote = $block->getCheckoutSession()->getQuote();
    $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();

    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
        echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
        echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
        echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
        echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
        echo "<br />";            
    }

    // Get total items and total quantity in cart

    $totalItems = $quote->getItemsCount();
    $totalQuantity = $quote->getItemsQty();

    //Get subtotal and grand total price of cart

    $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
    $grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();

    //Get billing and shipping addresses

    $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
    $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
```

> the only change was in this line

```
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Comment: I already to change my module namespace but it does not work for me I do not know what I need to do now?

Comment: can i see your checkout_cart_index.xml file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\History\Block\ViewQuote" name="viewquote" template="Magento_History::index.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>

Comment: this may be a cache issue. have you tried `cacheable ="false"` in xml ?

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: thank for your answer me. But I do not know what happens with my Magento. it always shows error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems() on null. I need to know which files I need to create, can you help me?

Comment: can you please check what you get into the `var_dump(get_class_methods($quote));` in phtml

Comment: Yes, can you please see below, has a comment and I had changed my code like that

Comment: you already have created required files, no need to add more files. just for clarification you only need 3 files, your Block file, checkout_cart_index.xml, phtml file that's ite.

Comment: Yes, I know and I already have that file, I just edit my code in Block file like the comment below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95609/discussion-between-mohit-rane-and-kite-hany).